# TimeOut expired : Sql Exception while using nHibernate

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, sqlperformance

After checking more details , I came to know about the below findings. I was unable to get the inner exceptions so I ran it in fiddler to check if I could get some information out of it.Fiddler had the below details

> [GenericADOException: could not execute query [ SELECT this_.CompanyId
>   as CompanyId0_30_, this_.HooversCompanyId as HooversC2_0_30_,
>   this_.DUNS as DUNS0_30_, this_.CompanyName as CompanyN4_0_30_,
>   this_.AddressLine1 as AddressL5_0_30_, this_.AddressLine2 as
>   AddressL6_0_30_, this_.State as State0_30_, this_.City as City0_30_,
>   this_.ZipCode as ZipCode0_30_, this_.CountryTelephoneAccessCode as
>   Country10_0_30_, this_.TelephoneNumber as Telepho11_0_30_,
>   this_.FaxNumber as FaxNumber0_30_, this_.Revenue as Revenue0_30_,
>   this_.FinancialYearEndDate as Financi14_0_30_, this_.EmployeesTotal as
>   Employe15_0_30_, this_.EmployeesHereTotal as Employe16_0_30_,
>   this_.LegalStructure as LegalSt17_0_30_, this_.ProfitLoss as
>   ProfitLoss0_30_, this_.NetWorth as NetWorth0_30_,
>   this_.HasSubsidariesIndicator as HasSubs20_0_30_,
>   this_.ITSpendingUpdateDate as ITSpend21_0_30_, this_.ITSpending as
>   ITSpending0_30_, this_.ITSpendingNextYearPrediction as
>   ITSpend23_0_30_, this_.ITSpendingGrowth as ITSpend24_0_30_,
>   this_.AuditCreatedDate as AuditCr25_0_30_, this_.AuditModifiedDate as
>   AuditMo26_0_30_, this_.Website as Website0_30_, this_.OwnershipTypeId
>   as Ownersh28_0_30_, this_.CompanyStatusId as Company29_0_30_,
>   this_.RecordTypeId as RecordT30_0_30_, this_.LocationTypeId as
>   Locatio31_0_30_, this_.ZipCodeId as ZipCodeId0_30_,
>   this_.PrimarySIC_Code as PrimarySIC33_0_30_, this_.StateId as
>   StateId0_30_, this_.CountryId as CountryId0_30_, this_.SWOTAnalysisId
>   as SWOTAna36_0_30_, primaryind2_.CompanyId as CompanyId32_,
>   primaryind2_.CompanyIndustryId as CompanyI1_32_,
>   primaryind2_.CompanyIndustryId as CompanyI1_8_0_,
>   primaryind2_.IsPrimary as IsPrimary8_0_, primaryind2_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId8_0_, primaryind2_.HIC as HIC8_0_, industry3_.HIC as HIC6_1_,
>   industry3_.Name as Name6_1_, industry3_.Level as Level6_1_,
>   industry3_.ParentHIC as ParentHIC6_1_, itspending4_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId33_, itspending4_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_33_,
>   itspending4_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_2_, itspending4_.Amount as
>   Amount14_2_, itspending4_.CompanyId as CompanyId14_2_,
>   itspending4_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_2_,
>   itspending5_.ITSpendingTypeID as ITSpendi1_15_3_, itspending5_.Name as
>   Name15_3_, itspending5_.ParentID as ParentID15_3_,
>   hardware6_.CompanyId as CompanyId34_, hardware6_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_34_, hardware6_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_4_,
>   hardware6_.Amount as Amount14_4_, hardware6_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_4_, hardware6_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_4_,
>   computingp7_.CompanyId as CompanyId35_, computingp7_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_35_, computingp7_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_5_,
>   computingp7_.Amount as Amount14_5_, computingp7_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_5_, computingp7_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_5_,
>   networking8_.CompanyId as CompanyId36_, networking8_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_36_, networking8_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_6_,
>   networking8_.Amount as Amount14_6_, networking8_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_6_, networking8_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_6_,
>   serversand9_.CompanyId as CompanyId37_, serversand9_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_37_, serversand9_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_7_,
>   serversand9_.Amount as Amount14_7_, serversand9_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_7_, serversand9_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_7_,
>   software10_.CompanyId as CompanyId38_, software10_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_38_, software10_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_8_,
>   software10_.Amount as Amount14_8_, software10_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_8_, software10_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_8_,
>   softwareli11_.CompanyId as CompanyId39_, softwareli11_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_39_, softwareli11_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_9_,
>   softwareli11_.Amount as Amount14_9_, softwareli11_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_9_, softwareli11_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_9_,
>   supportand12_.CompanyId as CompanyId40_, supportand12_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_40_, supportand12_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_10_,
>   supportand12_.Amount as Amount14_10_, supportand12_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_10_, supportand12_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_10_,
>   services13_.CompanyId as CompanyId41_, services13_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_41_, services13_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_11_,
>   services13_.Amount as Amount14_11_, services13_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_11_, services13_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_11_,
>   applicatio14_.CompanyId as CompanyId42_, applicatio14_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_42_, applicatio14_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_12_,
>   applicatio14_.Amount as Amount14_12_, applicatio14_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_12_, applicatio14_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_12_,
>   infrastruc15_.CompanyId as CompanyId43_, infrastruc15_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_43_, infrastruc15_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_13_,
>   infrastruc15_.Amount as Amount14_13_, infrastruc15_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_13_, infrastruc15_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_13_,
>   helpdeskan16_.CompanyId as CompanyId44_, helpdeskan16_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_44_, helpdeskan16_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_14_,
>   helpdeskan16_.Amount as Amount14_14_, helpdeskan16_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_14_, helpdeskan16_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_14_,
>   communicat17_.CompanyId as CompanyId45_, communicat17_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_45_, communicat17_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_15_,
>   communicat17_.Amount as Amount14_15_, communicat17_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_15_, communicat17_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_15_,
>   voiceservi18_.CompanyId as CompanyId46_, voiceservi18_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_46_, voiceservi18_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_16_,
>   voiceservi18_.Amount as Amount14_16_, voiceservi18_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_16_, voiceservi18_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_16_,
>   dataservic19_.CompanyId as CompanyId47_, dataservic19_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_47_, dataservic19_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_17_,
>   dataservic19_.Amount as Amount14_17_, dataservic19_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_17_, dataservic19_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_17_,
>   convergeds20_.CompanyId as CompanyId48_, convergeds20_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_48_, convergeds20_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_18_,
>   convergeds20_.Amount as Amount14_18_, convergeds20_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_18_, convergeds20_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_18_,
>   consulting21_.CompanyId as CompanyId49_, consulting21_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_49_, consulting21_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_19_,
>   consulting21_.Amount as Amount14_19_, consulting21_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_19_, consulting21_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_19_,
>   systemspla22_.CompanyId as CompanyId50_, systemspla22_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_50_, systemspla22_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_20_,
>   systemspla22_.Amount as Amount14_20_, systemspla22_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_20_, systemspla22_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_20_,
>   disasterre23_.CompanyId as CompanyId51_, disasterre23_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_51_, disasterre23_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_21_,
>   disasterre23_.Amount as Amount14_21_, disasterre23_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_21_, disasterre23_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_21_,
>   traininged24_.CompanyId as CompanyId52_, traininged24_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_52_, traininged24_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_22_,
>   traininged24_.Amount as Amount14_22_, traininged24_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_22_, traininged24_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_22_,
>   internalit25_.CompanyId as CompanyId53_, internalit25_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_53_, internalit25_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_23_,
>   internalit25_.Amount as Amount14_23_, internalit25_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_23_, internalit25_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_23_,
>   telco26_.CompanyId as CompanyId54_, telco26_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_54_, telco26_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_24_,
>   telco26_.Amount as Amount14_24_, telco26_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_24_, telco26_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_24_,
>   systemsint27_.CompanyId as CompanyId55_, systemsint27_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_55_, systemsint27_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_25_,
>   systemsint27_.Amount as Amount14_25_, systemsint27_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_25_, systemsint27_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_25_,
>   zipcode28_.ZipCodeId as ZipCodeId27_26_, zipcode28_.ZipCode as
>   ZipCode27_26_, siccode29_.Code as Code20_27_, siccode29_.Name as
>   Name20_27_, country30_.CountryId as CountryId4_28_, country30_.Name as
>   Name4_28_, country30_.GeographyId as Geograph3_4_28_,
>   contractsa31_.CompanyId as CompanyId3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.ActiveContractValue as ActiveCo2_3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.ActiveContractVolume as ActiveCo3_3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.TotalContractValue as TotalCon4_3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.TotalContractVolume as TotalCon5_3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.RelationshipVendor as Relation6_3_29_ FROM Company this_
>   left outer join CompanyIndustry primaryind2_ on
>   this_.CompanyId=primaryind2_.CompanyId and (primaryind2_.IsPrimary =
>   1) left outer join HooversIndustry industry3_ on
>   primaryind2_.HIC=industry3_.HIC left outer join ITSpending
>   itspending4_ on this_.CompanyId=itspending4_.CompanyId left outer join
>   ITSpendingType itspending5_ on
>   itspending4_.ITSpendingTypeId=itspending5_.ITSpendingTypeID left outer
>   join ITSpending hardware6_ on this_.CompanyId=hardware6_.CompanyId and
>   (hardware6_.ITSpendingTypeId = 2) left outer join ITSpending
>   computingp7_ on this_.CompanyId=computingp7_.CompanyId and
>   (computingp7_.ITSpendingTypeId = 12) left outer join ITSpending
>   networking8_ on this_.CompanyId=networking8_.CompanyId and
>   (networking8_.ITSpendingTypeId = 11) left outer join ITSpending
>   serversand9_ on this_.CompanyId=serversand9_.CompanyId and
>   (serversand9_.ITSpendingTypeId = 10) left outer join ITSpending
>   software10_ on this_.CompanyId=software10_.CompanyId and
>   (software10_.ITSpendingTypeId = 3) left outer join ITSpending
>   softwareli11_ on this_.CompanyId=softwareli11_.CompanyId and
>   (softwareli11_.ITSpendingTypeId = 15) left outer join ITSpending
>   supportand12_ on this_.CompanyId=supportand12_.CompanyId and
>   (supportand12_.ITSpendingTypeId = 16) left outer join ITSpending
>   services13_ on this_.CompanyId=services13_.CompanyId and
>   (services13_.ITSpendingTypeId = 4) left outer join ITSpending
>   applicatio14_ on this_.CompanyId=applicatio14_.CompanyId and
>   (applicatio14_.ITSpendingTypeId = 19) left outer join ITSpending
>   infrastruc15_ on this_.CompanyId=infrastruc15_.CompanyId and
>   (infrastruc15_.ITSpendingTypeId = 20) left outer join ITSpending
>   helpdeskan16_ on this_.CompanyId=helpdeskan16_.CompanyId and
>   (helpdeskan16_.ITSpendingTypeId = 21) left outer join ITSpending
>   communicat17_ on this_.CompanyId=communicat17_.CompanyId and
>   (communicat17_.ITSpendingTypeId = 5) left outer join ITSpending
>   voiceservi18_ on this_.CompanyId=voiceservi18_.CompanyId and
>   (voiceservi18_.ITSpendingTypeId = 24) left outer join ITSpending
>   dataservic19_ on this_.CompanyId=dataservic19_.CompanyId and
>   (dataservic19_.ITSpendingTypeId = 25) left outer join ITSpending
>   convergeds20_ on this_.CompanyId=convergeds20_.CompanyId and
>   (convergeds20_.ITSpendingTypeId = 26) left outer join ITSpending
>   consulting21_ on this_.CompanyId=consulting21_.CompanyId and
>   (consulting21_.ITSpendingTypeId = 6) left outer join ITSpending
>   systemspla22_ on this_.CompanyId=systemspla22_.CompanyId and
>   (systemspla22_.ITSpendingTypeId = 29) left outer join ITSpending
>   disasterre23_ on this_.CompanyId=disasterre23_.CompanyId and
>   (disasterre23_.ITSpendingTypeId = 30) left outer join ITSpending
>   traininged24_ on this_.CompanyId=traininged24_.CompanyId and
>   (traininged24_.ITSpendingTypeId = 31) left outer join ITSpending
>   internalit25_ on this_.CompanyId=internalit25_.CompanyId and
>   (internalit25_.ITSpendingTypeId = 38) left outer join ITSpending
>   telco26_ on this_.CompanyId=telco26_.CompanyId and
>   (telco26_.ITSpendingTypeId = 35) left outer join ITSpending
>   systemsint27_ on this_.CompanyId=systemsint27_.CompanyId and
>   (systemsint27_.ITSpendingTypeId = 36) left outer join ZipCode
>   zipcode28_ on this_.ZipCodeId=zipcode28_.ZipCodeId left outer join
>   SICCode siccode29_ on this_.PrimarySIC_Code=siccode29_.Code left outer
>   join Country country30_ on this_.CountryId=country30_.CountryId left
>   outer join CompanyContractAggregation contractsa31_ on
>   this_.CompanyId=contractsa31_.CompanyId WHERE this_.CompanyId in (@p0)
>   ]   Name:cp0 - Value:3506 [SQL: SELECT this_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId0_30_, this_.HooversCompanyId as HooversC2_0_30_, this_.DUNS
>   as DUNS0_30_, this_.CompanyName as CompanyN4_0_30_, this_.AddressLine1
>   as AddressL5_0_30_, this_.AddressLine2 as AddressL6_0_30_, this_.State
>   as State0_30_, this_.City as City0_30_, this_.ZipCode as ZipCode0_30_,
>   this_.CountryTelephoneAccessCode as Country10_0_30_,
>   this_.TelephoneNumber as Telepho11_0_30_, this_.FaxNumber as
>   FaxNumber0_30_, this_.Revenue as Revenue0_30_,
>   this_.FinancialYearEndDate as Financi14_0_30_, this_.EmployeesTotal as
>   Employe15_0_30_, this_.EmployeesHereTotal as Employe16_0_30_,
>   this_.LegalStructure as LegalSt17_0_30_, this_.ProfitLoss as
>   ProfitLoss0_30_, this_.NetWorth as NetWorth0_30_,
>   this_.HasSubsidariesIndicator as HasSubs20_0_30_,
>   this_.ITSpendingUpdateDate as ITSpend21_0_30_, this_.ITSpending as
>   ITSpending0_30_, this_.ITSpendingNextYearPrediction as
>   ITSpend23_0_30_, this_.ITSpendingGrowth as ITSpend24_0_30_,
>   this_.AuditCreatedDate as AuditCr25_0_30_, this_.AuditModifiedDate as
>   AuditMo26_0_30_, this_.Website as Website0_30_, this_.OwnershipTypeId
>   as Ownersh28_0_30_, this_.CompanyStatusId as Company29_0_30_,
>   this_.RecordTypeId as RecordT30_0_30_, this_.LocationTypeId as
>   Locatio31_0_30_, this_.ZipCodeId as ZipCodeId0_30_,
>   this_.PrimarySIC_Code as PrimarySIC33_0_30_, this_.StateId as
>   StateId0_30_, this_.CountryId as CountryId0_30_, this_.SWOTAnalysisId
>   as SWOTAna36_0_30_, primaryind2_.CompanyId as CompanyId32_,
>   primaryind2_.CompanyIndustryId as CompanyI1_32_,
>   primaryind2_.CompanyIndustryId as CompanyI1_8_0_,
>   primaryind2_.IsPrimary as IsPrimary8_0_, primaryind2_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId8_0_, primaryind2_.HIC as HIC8_0_, industry3_.HIC as HIC6_1_,
>   industry3_.Name as Name6_1_, industry3_.Level as Level6_1_,
>   industry3_.ParentHIC as ParentHIC6_1_, itspending4_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId33_, itspending4_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_33_,
>   itspending4_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_2_, itspending4_.Amount as
>   Amount14_2_, itspending4_.CompanyId as CompanyId14_2_,
>   itspending4_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_2_,
>   itspending5_.ITSpendingTypeID as ITSpendi1_15_3_, itspending5_.Name as
>   Name15_3_, itspending5_.ParentID as ParentID15_3_,
>   hardware6_.CompanyId as CompanyId34_, hardware6_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_34_, hardware6_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_4_,
>   hardware6_.Amount as Amount14_4_, hardware6_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_4_, hardware6_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_4_,
>   computingp7_.CompanyId as CompanyId35_, computingp7_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_35_, computingp7_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_5_,
>   computingp7_.Amount as Amount14_5_, computingp7_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_5_, computingp7_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_5_,
>   networking8_.CompanyId as CompanyId36_, networking8_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_36_, networking8_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_6_,
>   networking8_.Amount as Amount14_6_, networking8_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_6_, networking8_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_6_,
>   serversand9_.CompanyId as CompanyId37_, serversand9_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_37_, serversand9_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_7_,
>   serversand9_.Amount as Amount14_7_, serversand9_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_7_, serversand9_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_7_,
>   software10_.CompanyId as CompanyId38_, software10_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_38_, software10_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_8_,
>   software10_.Amount as Amount14_8_, software10_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_8_, software10_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_8_,
>   softwareli11_.CompanyId as CompanyId39_, softwareli11_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_39_, softwareli11_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_9_,
>   softwareli11_.Amount as Amount14_9_, softwareli11_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_9_, softwareli11_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_9_,
>   supportand12_.CompanyId as CompanyId40_, supportand12_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_40_, supportand12_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_10_,
>   supportand12_.Amount as Amount14_10_, supportand12_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_10_, supportand12_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_10_,
>   services13_.CompanyId as CompanyId41_, services13_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_41_, services13_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_11_,
>   services13_.Amount as Amount14_11_, services13_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_11_, services13_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_11_,
>   applicatio14_.CompanyId as CompanyId42_, applicatio14_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_42_, applicatio14_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_12_,
>   applicatio14_.Amount as Amount14_12_, applicatio14_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_12_, applicatio14_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_12_,
>   infrastruc15_.CompanyId as CompanyId43_, infrastruc15_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_43_, infrastruc15_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_13_,
>   infrastruc15_.Amount as Amount14_13_, infrastruc15_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_13_, infrastruc15_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_13_,
>   helpdeskan16_.CompanyId as CompanyId44_, helpdeskan16_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_44_, helpdeskan16_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_14_,
>   helpdeskan16_.Amount as Amount14_14_, helpdeskan16_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_14_, helpdeskan16_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_14_,
>   communicat17_.CompanyId as CompanyId45_, communicat17_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_45_, communicat17_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_15_,
>   communicat17_.Amount as Amount14_15_, communicat17_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_15_, communicat17_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_15_,
>   voiceservi18_.CompanyId as CompanyId46_, voiceservi18_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_46_, voiceservi18_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_16_,
>   voiceservi18_.Amount as Amount14_16_, voiceservi18_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_16_, voiceservi18_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_16_,
>   dataservic19_.CompanyId as CompanyId47_, dataservic19_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_47_, dataservic19_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_17_,
>   dataservic19_.Amount as Amount14_17_, dataservic19_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_17_, dataservic19_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_17_,
>   convergeds20_.CompanyId as CompanyId48_, convergeds20_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_48_, convergeds20_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_18_,
>   convergeds20_.Amount as Amount14_18_, convergeds20_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_18_, convergeds20_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_18_,
>   consulting21_.CompanyId as CompanyId49_, consulting21_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_49_, consulting21_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_19_,
>   consulting21_.Amount as Amount14_19_, consulting21_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_19_, consulting21_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_19_,
>   systemspla22_.CompanyId as CompanyId50_, systemspla22_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_50_, systemspla22_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_20_,
>   systemspla22_.Amount as Amount14_20_, systemspla22_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_20_, systemspla22_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_20_,
>   disasterre23_.CompanyId as CompanyId51_, disasterre23_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_51_, disasterre23_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_21_,
>   disasterre23_.Amount as Amount14_21_, disasterre23_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_21_, disasterre23_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_21_,
>   traininged24_.CompanyId as CompanyId52_, traininged24_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_52_, traininged24_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_22_,
>   traininged24_.Amount as Amount14_22_, traininged24_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_22_, traininged24_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_22_,
>   internalit25_.CompanyId as CompanyId53_, internalit25_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_53_, internalit25_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_23_,
>   internalit25_.Amount as Amount14_23_, internalit25_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_23_, internalit25_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_23_,
>   telco26_.CompanyId as CompanyId54_, telco26_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_54_, telco26_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_24_,
>   telco26_.Amount as Amount14_24_, telco26_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_24_, telco26_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_24_,
>   systemsint27_.CompanyId as CompanyId55_, systemsint27_.ITSpendingId as
>   ITSpendi1_55_, systemsint27_.ITSpendingId as ITSpendi1_14_25_,
>   systemsint27_.Amount as Amount14_25_, systemsint27_.CompanyId as
>   CompanyId14_25_, systemsint27_.ITSpendingTypeId as ITSpendi3_14_25_,
>   zipcode28_.ZipCodeId as ZipCodeId27_26_, zipcode28_.ZipCode as
>   ZipCode27_26_, siccode29_.Code as Code20_27_, siccode29_.Name as
>   Name20_27_, country30_.CountryId as CountryId4_28_, country30_.Name as
>   Name4_28_, country30_.GeographyId as Geograph3_4_28_,
>   contractsa31_.CompanyId as CompanyId3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.ActiveContractValue as ActiveCo2_3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.ActiveContractVolume as ActiveCo3_3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.TotalContractValue as TotalCon4_3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.TotalContractVolume as TotalCon5_3_29_,
>   contractsa31_.RelationshipVendor as Relation6_3_29_ FROM Company this_
>   left outer join CompanyIndustry primaryind2_ on
>   this_.CompanyId=primaryind2_.CompanyId and (primaryind2_.IsPrimary =
>   1) left outer join HooversIndustry industry3_ on
>   primaryind2_.HIC=industry3_.HIC left outer join ITSpending
>   itspending4_ on this_.CompanyId=itspending4_.CompanyId left outer join
>   ITSpendingType itspending5_ on
>   itspending4_.ITSpendingTypeId=itspending5_.ITSpendingTypeID left outer
>   join ITSpending hardware6_ on this_.CompanyId=hardware6_.CompanyId and
>   (hardware6_.ITSpendingTypeId = 2) left outer join ITSpending
>   computingp7_ on this_.CompanyId=computingp7_.CompanyId and
>   (computingp7_.ITSpendingTypeId = 12) left outer join ITSpending
>   networking8_ on this_.CompanyId=networking8_.CompanyId and
>   (networking8_.ITSpendingTypeId = 11) left outer join ITSpending
>   serversand9_ on this_.CompanyId=serversand9_.CompanyId and
>   (serversand9_.ITSpendingTypeId = 10) left outer join ITSpending
>   software10_ on this_.CompanyId=software10_.CompanyId and
>   (software10_.ITSpendingTypeId = 3) left outer join ITSpending
>   softwareli11_ on this_.CompanyId=softwareli11_.CompanyId and
>   (softwareli11_.ITSpendingTypeId = 15) left outer join ITSpending
>   supportand12_ on this_.CompanyId=supportand12_.CompanyId and
>   (supportand12_.ITSpendingTypeId = 16) left outer join ITSpending
>   services13_ on this_.CompanyId=services13_.CompanyId and
>   (services13_.ITSpendingTypeId = 4) left outer join ITSpending
>   applicatio14_ on this_.CompanyId=applicatio14_.CompanyId and
>   (applicatio14_.ITSpendingTypeId = 19) left outer join ITSpending
>   infrastruc15_ on this_.CompanyId=infrastruc15_.CompanyId and
>   (infrastruc15_.ITSpendingTypeId = 20) left outer join ITSpending
>   helpdeskan16_ on this_.CompanyId=helpdeskan16_.CompanyId and
>   (helpdeskan16_.ITSpendingTypeId = 21) left outer join ITSpending
>   communicat17_ on this_.CompanyId=communicat17_.CompanyId and
>   (communicat17_.ITSpendingTypeId = 5) left outer join ITSpending
>   voiceservi18_ on this_.CompanyId=voiceservi18_.CompanyId and
>   (voiceservi18_.ITSpendingTypeId = 24) left outer join ITSpending
>   dataservic19_ on this_.CompanyId=dataservic19_.CompanyId and
>   (dataservic19_.ITSpendingTypeId = 25) left outer join ITSpending
>   convergeds20_ on this_.CompanyId=convergeds20_.CompanyId and
>   (convergeds20_.ITSpendingTypeId = 26) left outer join ITSpending
>   consulting21_ on this_.CompanyId=consulting21_.CompanyId and
>   (consulting21_.ITSpendingTypeId = 6) left outer join ITSpending
>   systemspla22_ on this_.CompanyId=systemspla22_.CompanyId and
>   (systemspla22_.ITSpendingTypeId = 29) left outer join ITSpending
>   disasterre23_ on this_.CompanyId=disasterre23_.CompanyId and
>   (disasterre23_.ITSpendingTypeId = 30) left outer join ITSpending
>   traininged24_ on this_.CompanyId=traininged24_.CompanyId and
>   (traininged24_.ITSpendingTypeId = 31) left outer join ITSpending
>   internalit25_ on this_.CompanyId=internalit25_.CompanyId and
>   (internalit25_.ITSpendingTypeId = 38) left outer join ITSpending
>   telco26_ on this_.CompanyId=telco26_.CompanyId and
>   (telco26_.ITSpendingTypeId = 35) left outer join ITSpending
>   systemsint27_ on this_.CompanyId=systemsint27_.CompanyId and
>   (systemsint27_.ITSpendingTypeId = 36) left outer join ZipCode
>   zipcode28_ on this_.ZipCodeId=zipcode28_.ZipCodeId left outer join
>   SICCode siccode29_ on this_.PrimarySIC_Code=siccode29_.Code left outer
>   join Country country30_ on this_.CountryId=country30_.CountryId left
>   outer join CompanyContractAggregation contractsa31_ on
>   this_.CompanyId=contractsa31_.CompanyId WHERE this_.CompanyId in
>   (@p0)]]    NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +637
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters) +23
>   NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor
>   session) +60    NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl
>   criteria, IList results) +1025
>   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results) +63
>   NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List() +79
>   Ovum.Ictop.Dal.CustomRepositories.CompanyRepository.Criteria(CriteriaInstance
>   criteria, Nullable`1 pageIndex, Nullable`1 pageSize, Nullable`1
>   maxCount) in
>   c:\GIT-ICTOP\Ovum_Ictop\Ovum.Ictop.Admin.Dal\CustomRepositories\CompanyRepository.cs:69    Ovum.Ictop.Bl.ServiceWrappers.CompanyService.GetCompanyByCriteria(CriteriaInstance
>   criteria, Nullable`1 pageIndex, Nullable`1 pageSize, Nullable`1
>   maxCount) in
>   c:\GIT-ICTOP\Ovum_Ictop\Ovum.Ictop.Bl\ServiceWrappers\CompanyService.cs:289
>   Ovum.Ictop.Web.Areas.CA.Controllers.SearchController.GetCompanyByLikeName(String
>   name, Int32 numberPage) in
>   c:\GIT-ICTOP\Ovum_Ictop\Ovum.Ictop.Web\Areas\CA\Controllers\SearchController.cs:45
>   Ovum.Ictop.Web.Areas.CA.Controllers.SearchController.Search(String
>   companyName) in
>   c:\GIT-ICTOP\Ovum_Ictop\Ovum.Ictop.Web\Areas\CA\Controllers\SearchController.cs:29
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b*_12()
>   +129    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
>   +826106    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,
>   IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +825328
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +335    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b*_5()
>   +62    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b*_0()
>   +20    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b*_d()
>   +54    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +469    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375

Comment: What is the innermost inner exception?

Comment: I am not able to get the inner most exception as I am unable to debug the same. This exception is coming only on production.

Comment: Can you have the DBA watch the SQL being sent? It's timing out, so if it worked before either a query has changed, indexes are broken, or the amount of data has increased. Getting that SQL is key to figuring it out

Comment: I have edited my question with more details, but I want to place a piece of code which is causing the issue and my thoughts about it. Due to character limitation I am unable to do it here .

Comment: The above select statement generated from Nhibernate is a result of eager fetching . When I was searching about this in google found this link <http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html>. As per this link, it is a problem with cartesian product which I am getting while querying.

Comment: You could make use of some `LazyLoad` on your object graph. Take a look at that query, it's joining the whole database!